# Using enum for member in a class

Tags: typescript

I have the following definitions:

```
enum AccountTypes {
  CHECKING = 'Checking',
  SAVINGS = 'Savings',
}

export class BankAccount {
  id: number;
  label?: string;
  type: AccountTypes;

  constructor(init?: Partial<BankAccount>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

... when I try to do something like:

```
const account = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: 'CHECKING',
};
const something = new BankAccount(account);
```

I get the following error:

> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"CHECKING" | "SAVINGS" | undefined'.

I also did some test with:

```
export class BankAccount {
  id: number;
  label?: string;
  type: keyof typeof AccountTypes;

  constructor(init?: Partial<BankAccount>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

... but it didn't work.

**note:**

this case is special, it is not like I'm not using the enum definition, basically my problem is that I defined a `js` file with some definitions to use on my mock tests, so basically I have that plain object like if we get it from the server, then I try to define that plain object on my test and I got that error.

Comment: Change `'CHECKING'` to `AccountTypes.CHECKING`

Comment: Indeed, why define an enum if you're just going to use strings anyway?

Comment: Different use cases for different features. What you want is a union type, not an enum: `class BankAccount {type: "CHECKING" | "SAVINGS"} `

Comment: added a note at the end explaining why I'm not using the enum entries :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the 1st. approach is that you're trying to pass a string while it expects an enum member.

With the 2nd. approach, it just doesn't work because you are trying to pass "CHECKINGS" instead of the "Checking" in the case.

To solve this problem, you have the following options:

### 1. Use enum member:

```
const account = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: AccountTypes.CHECKING,
};
const something = new BankAccount(account);
```

### 2. Type like you did in 2nd. approach (`keyof typeof AccountTypes`):

```
const account = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: 'Checking',
};
const something = new BankAccount(account);
```

### 3. Use type alias:

```
type AccountTypes = 'Checking' | 'Savings';

const account = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: 'Checking',
} as const;

// or

const account = {
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: 'Checking' as AccountTypes,
};

// or

const account: Partial<BankAccount> = { // It would be better to create an interface here
  id: 1,
  label: 'John Doe: Chase Checking ****1892',
  type: 'Checking',
};

const something = new BankAccount(account);
```

---

Note that if you opt-in for `enums`, it would be better to use `const enum`, because they're fully erasable in build generation.

Comment: very good explanation @developer033 :) I really appreciate it. I added a note at the end of the question explaining why I can use `AccountTypes.CHECKING` directly into the definition, but this solves a lot of questions as well :)

Comment: @PrinceHernandez so, the 2nd or 3rd. solution doesn't solve this?

Comment: @developer033's last suggestion should do it. Try using an explicit type annotation for `account`. That is: `const account: BankAccount = { ... }`